# Qual a solução para essa comparação?

Tags: c

estou programando em C para uma matéria da faculdade, devemos ler um arquivo e criar alguns métodos de lista para usar no programa, basicamente devo implementar a estrutura de uma lista e utilizar em uma solução para um programa solicitado. Meu problema é que, meu código funciona e está sintaticamente correto, porém existe uma comparação de dois itens que não está funcionando, o que tá afetando no funcionamento geral do meu programa (pois não deveria inserir uma informação mais de uma vez na lista), fiz o debbugin e descobri que a função finde não retorna em momento algum aux (Que é um ponteiro), isso faz com que meu programa insira varias vezes a mesma informação (caso eu coloque no aquivo que o programa lê), tenho outro problema também, meu programa lê strings com acentuação e mesmo usando o locale, a aplicação não é corrigida, se tiverem alguma dica quanto a isso, seria de grande ajuda. Segue meu código:

Observações gerais, no meu fscanf eu tenho um if que verifica se o find == null, isso significa que o find percorreu a lista toda e não encontrou um item ele retorna null, caso ele encontre oq foi passando no finde for encontrado, ele retorna aux, thats my problem, se eu botar pra inserir 3 itens iguais, no finde ele verifica a função if (aux->item.nome== x.nome && aux->item.estado == x.estado), não chega a entrar pra retornar aux, oq ta fazendo entrar dados repetidos no meu programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar strings você precisa usar uma função específica, `strcmp` ou `strncmp` (preferível).

```
TipoApontador find(TipoItem x, TipoLista* lista)
{
  TipoApontador aux;
  if (lista->primeiro != NULL)
  {
    aux = lista->primeiro;
    while (aux != NULL)
    {
      // if (aux->item.nome== x.nome && aux->item.estado == x.estado)
      //   return aux;
      if (strncmp(aux->item.nome, x.nome, 100) == 0 && strncmp(aux->item.estado, x.estado, 100) == 0)
        return aux;
      aux = aux->prox;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: No caso, pra usar o strcmp precisa incluir a biblioteca cstring, minha duvida é se isso faz parte do C, ou C++. Meu trabalho precisa ser todo em c

Comment: incluir o header <string.h>...para saber qual header incluir para uma função em C ou C++ procure no Google assim: "man nome_função" (Linux), ou "msdn nome_funcao" (Windows)...use a função "strncmp", é mais segura que "strcmp"

Comment: Muito obrigado !!

Comment: marque essa solução como aceita, assim ganho mais uns pontinhos :) (clique na marca de "ok" que está em cinza abaixo da flechinha inferior à esquerda)